# How to set the gridview in flutter? First row 2 card, and second row 1 card only

Tags: flutter, gridview, view, grid

I'm recently new in flutter. I started to create a gridview. But I had a problem when i want to set the order like what I want. I want to set the first row width 2 card, and the second row width 1 card only.
[Here's what it look like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hckXS.png)

```
Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                        childAspectRatio: widthScreen / heightScreen,
                        primary: false,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                            ),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Personal Data', style: cardTextStyle,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                            ),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Personal Data', style: cardTextStyle,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                            ),
                            elevation: 4,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text('Personal Data', style: cardTextStyle,)
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                  )
```

[And this is the view that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ayq9a.png)
Thanks for the help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57833498/10285344

See this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need these 3 cards and you don't want to build them dynamically, you better use a column with 2 rows.

```
     Column(
        children: [
          Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: card),
                Expanded(child: card),
              ]
          ),
          card,
        ]
    )
```

The cards in the `Row` will have parent half width, and the separate `card` will expand to full.
You may need to set width to `double.maxFinite` in your second card without the Row as it has no constraint by default to match parent width.
You need to set height for the cards, if you want to keep the aspect ratio, you can use `AspectRatio` widget.