# Image view in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a difficult problem in the newfeeds of app.
Users post multiple images of different sizes, and what we want is to be displayed in the same fashion as on the facebook app.
I'm really one keyword or idea to do this.

Thanks!

[This is UI about what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UouGH.jpg)

Comment: Does this solve your issue --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833400/dynamically-change-the-gridview-crossaxis-count-to-populate-dynamic-columns-in-f?

Answer (score 0):

If you want show widget same your image, I think you can try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Features

- Configurable cross-axis count or max cross-axis extent like the GridView
- Tiles can have a fixed main-axis extent, or a multiple of the cell's length.
- Configurable main-axis and cross-axis margins between tiles.
- SliverStaggeredGrid for using in a CustomScrollView.
- Staggered and Spannable grid layouts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).